# Weird behaviour trying to roll an insertAfter() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of `class="section"` divs which I want to move with up/down buttons inside of them. The up button works alright, but the down button I have to press twice to get the div to move down a spot. Can't get my head around it. It's the same in Firefox as in Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

The HTML:

```
<div class="section">
 .  
 .  //content goes here  
 .
  <button class="up" type="button">up</button>
  <button class="down" type="button">down</button>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
//event listeners  
var classup = document.getElementsByClassName("up");
var classdown = document.getElementsByClassName("down");
for (var i=0; i<classup.length; i++) {
    classup[i].addEventListener('click', upf, false);
    classdown[i].addEventListener('click', downf, false);
}

//functions

function downf() {
    var temp = this.parentNode;
    temp.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, temp.nextSibling.nextSibling);
}

function upf() {
    var temp = this.parentNode;
    temp.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, temp.previousElementSibling);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've use `.nextSibling` instead of `.nextElementSibling`. This will move your section after the following whitespace text node when clicking `down`.

```
function downf() {
    var section = this.parentNode;
    if (section.nextElementSibling)
        section.parentNode.insertBefore(section, section.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling);
}
```